# How to change sub label or main label auto based on condition in roomle?

Tags: roomle

I want to the sub label will change when the properties changes. Of source, I will set name of lable in event update.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrbpS.png)

Comment: If the provided answer helped you, please accept the answer to acknowledge the help of the person doing an effort to help you

Answer (score 2):

You can find how the label and sub label is put together in the [docs](https://docs.roomle.com/web/guides/tutorial/configurator/08_UI_customization.html#price-and-name).

Since I don't think it's possible to change of the root component label in the Roomle script, the label cannot be changed on demand.